# Регулярные выражения: удаление BBCode

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, bbcode

Есть небольшая регулярка, она ищет все bb-коды, `[b][/b],[i][/i]` и удаляет их:

```
\[.+(.)\]
```

Но, проверяя эту регулярку в `regex101`, bb-код `[b]123[/b]`, выделяет как целый текст.
Как сделать так, чтобы он выделял только bb-код, не затрагивая сам текст?

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться выражением вида

```
\[[^\]]+\]
```

Т.е. примерно так

```
<?php
$text = 'Текст [b]123[/b]';
echo preg_replace('/\[[^\]]+\]/', '', $text);
```

Comment: Он выделяет только 1 символ bb кода, [b], а дальше нет...

Comment: А вы чем проверяете? Попробуйте выполнить скрипт из примера.

Comment: А, всё, правильнее будет так, /\[[^\]]+\]/g

Comment: Проверяю через сайт regex101

Comment: Меня смутил тэг php, дело в том, что не все реализации реглулярных выражений выполняются множественную замену, некоторые, да, по умолчанию находят только первое вхождение.

Comment: В любом случае, спасибо. Помогло!

Comment: Сложновато однако ... `\[.+?]` работает не хуже. Может конечно обратную косую добавить перед `]` но как я понимаю большинство движков регулярок ее тут не требуют

Comment: @Mike, `[ нет, [b]хуже[/b] ]`.

Comment: `(?:(\[.\]))(.+?)(?>(\[\/.\]*))`

Comment: @in1, или возможно так: `(?:(\[(.)\]))(.+?)(?>(\[\/(.)\]*))`